# I want to list last 20 entries from event log using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to list the last 20 entries from application log. What I did so far is here:

```
Dim eventLogApp As New System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application")
        Dim eventLogEntry As System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry
        Dim eventCntr As Integer = 1
        For Each eventLogEntry In eventLogApp.Entries

            If eventLogEntry.InstanceId = "1000" Then

                Me.ListBox5.Items.Add("Event Number:" & eventCntr)
                Me.ListBox5.Items.Add(eventLogEntry.Source.ToString)
                Me.ListBox5.Items.Add(eventLogEntry.Message.ToString)

                Me.ListBox5.Items.Add("-----------------------------------------------")
                eventCntr = eventCntr + 1
                If eventCntr = 20 Then Exit Sub

                Me.ListBox5.Refresh()
            End If
        Next
```

Right now it will list but from older to newer logs which I don't really need. I want to list only new entries.

Comment: [EventLogEntryCollection.CopyTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrycollection.copyto)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Entries.Reverse()` before for loop so that you will get the last 20 entries